# Intellij IDEA regex character class may not be used inside character range

Tags: javascript, regex, intellij-idea

[image: The error form intellij idea]

IDEA will not allow this error and i have not been able to find an option to turn off these kinds of errors.  does anyone know how to fix the error or turn off the warning. The javascript works fine only IDEA sees this as a problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are creating a range by using the **hyphen(-)** in mid of your character class. You should move it to either end.

Also, note that you don't need to escape the regex meta-characters inside the character class. They loose their meanings in there.

So, just use:

```
[-\w._+%]
```